# Why cant I access the mountpoint directory of my created volume after container is deleted

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have created a container and mounted a volume with it.
This is the docker command I am executing to build and run the container .

```
docker build -t wrapperscript . ;; docker run -it --name=wrapperscript -p 7997-8010:7997-8010 -e MARKLOGIC_INIT=true -e MARKLOGIC_ADMIN_USERNAME=admin -e MARKLOGIC_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin@123 -e MARKLOGIC_WALLET_PASSWORD=admin@123 -e MARKLOGIC_HOSTNAME=localhost --mount source=MarkLogic,target=/var/lib/docker/volumes/MarkLogic/_data wrapperscript:latest
```

And I then deleted the container and wanted to access the mount directory, but I found its not present after the directory path: /var/lib

When I run **docker volume inspect MarkLogic**, I see that the volume exists.

How can I access the mount directory even when my container is deleted. Is the mount directory tied with the active containers in which it is mounted to?

Comment: If you want to directly access files in the volume, I'd suggest using a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) rather than a named volume; you should never be digging around by hand in `/var/lib/docker` (and it may not be accessible on Docker Desktop or other VM-based setups).  Looking at that `--mount` option I'm also wondering if you're not mounting the directory on to the right container path.

Answer (score 0):

The way I look at volumes is by running an interactive container and mounting the volume to it.

You could run a debian container like this

```
docker run --rm -it --mount source=MarkLogic,target=/myvolume debian
```

Then, inside the container, go to `/myvolume` and look at the volume content.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I already tried that. It does not allow me to access the files mentioned in the target path when I shut down the container. My requirement is to access the filesystem from my local host machine even when the container is dropped. I have also tried to do bind mount but that also did not allow to find the path in my local host machine.